# How to draw a circle?

Tags: c, algorithm, visual-studio

So, I wrote a little code to display to draw circles. It kinda works, but in a really janky way. This is the output of running the program and inputting `6`:

```
 O       O
O         O
           O
           O
           O
           O
           O
           O
           O
O         O
 O       O
  OOOOOOO
```

Not looking great.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    int num, dist, x, y;
    printf("Enter the Radius of the Circle: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &num);
    {
        for (x = 1; x <= num * 2; x++)
        {
            for (y = 1; y <= num * 2; y++)
            {
                dist = sqrt((x - num) * (x - num) + (y - num) * (y - num));
                {
                    if (dist==num)
                    {
                        printf("O");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf(" ");
                    }
                }

            }
            printf("\n");

        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code, searched around the web for answers, it might be the placement of the "new line" code. Tried different spots, nope.

Comment: I think `dist` will rarely be _exactly equal_ to `num`, because https://0.30000000000000004.com, so you could instead check the distance between `dist` and `num` like: `if (abs(dist - num) < 0.01)`

Comment: @ForceBru Tried that and "dist<num+0.5 && dist>num-0.5". No luck.

Comment: What was your input?

Comment: @JL2210 input was 6.

Comment: Initialize X and Y with 0, it would be an improvement in your circle

Comment: Try Bresenham's circle drawing algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your two `for` loop should start from `0`:

```
for (x = 0; x <= num * 2; x++)
{
    for (y = 0; y <= num * 2; y++)
    {
        dist = sqrt((x - num) * (x - num) + (y - num) * (y - num));
        {
            if (dist==num)
            {
                printf("O");
            }
            else
            {
                printf(" ");
            }
        }

    }
    printf("\n");

}
```

You are probably missing the first column and the first row.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote one once, but mine just uses summations and subtractions, no multiplications (except one square, at the beginning) using *The Bresenham Algorithm*.  Here is the code. (you can get it also from [github](https://github.com/mojadita/bresenham.git))

```
/* bresenham.c -- program to draw ASCII circles with Bresenham's algorithm.
 * Author: Luis Colorado <luicoloradourcola@gmail.com>
 * Date: Wed Jan 11 10:50:17 EET 2017
 * Disclaimer: (C) 2017 LUIS COLORADO. ALL RIGHTS RESERVED.
 * BSD 3-Clause License
 * 
 * Copyright (c) 2017, Luis Colorado
 * All rights reserved.
 * 
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
 * 
 * * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this
 *   list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 * 
 * * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
 *   this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
 *   and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 * 
 * * Neither the name of the copyright holder nor the names of its
 *   contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived from
 *   this software without specific prior written permission.
 * 
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
 * AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
 * IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
 * DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE
 * FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
 * DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR
 * SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER
 * CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY,
 * OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
 * OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */

#include <errno.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define FL_FILL     (1 << 0)
#define FL_TRACE    (1 << 1)

#define F(x) "%s:%d:%s: " x, __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__

/* draws a horizontal line at row y, between x1 and x2 */
static void hline(int x1, int x2, int y)
{
    static char theLine[] =
    "*****************************************"
    "*****************************************"
    "*****************************************"
    "*****************************************"
    "*****************************************"
    "*****************************************"
    "*****************************************"
    "*****************************************"
    "*****************************************"
    "*****************************************"
    "*****************************************"
    "*****************************************";
#define THE_LINE_LENGTH (sizeof theLine - 1)
    int count = (x2 - x1 + 1) << 1;

    printf("\033[%d;%dH", y, x1<<1);
    while (count >= THE_LINE_LENGTH) {
        fputs(theLine, stdout);
        count -= THE_LINE_LENGTH;
    } /* while */
    printf("%.*s", count, theLine);
} /* hline */

/* draws a dot at coordinates (x, y) */
static void dot(int x, int y)
{
    printf("\033[%d;%dH*", y, x<<1);
} /* dot */

/* draws a circle of radius r and center at (cx, cy) */
void bh(int r, int cx, int cy, int flags)
{
    int r2 = r*r + r;
    int x = 0, x2 = 0, dx2 = 1;
    int y = r, y2 = y*y, dy2 = 2*y - 1;
    int sum = r2;

    while(x <= y) {
        if (flags & FL_TRACE) {
            printf(F("x=%3d, x2=%5d, dx2=%3d, y=%3d, y2=%5d, dy2=%3d, sum=%5d\n"),
                x, x2, dx2, y, y2, dy2, sum);
        } else {
            if (flags & FL_FILL) {
                       hline(cx - y, cx + y, cy + x);
                if (x) hline(cx - y, cx + y, cy - x);
            } else {
                             dot(cx - y, cy + x); if (y) dot(cx + y, cy + x);
                    if (x) { dot(cx - y, cy - x); if (y) dot(cx + y, cy - x); }
                if (x != y) {
                             dot(cx - x, cy - y); if (x) dot(cx + x, cy - y);
                    if (y) { dot(cx - x, cy + y); if (x) dot(cx + x, cy + y); }
                }
            } /* if */
        } /* if */

        sum -= dx2;
        if (sum <= y2) {
            if (!(flags & FL_TRACE) && (flags & FL_FILL) && (x != y)) {
                       hline(cx - x, cx + x, cy - y);
                if (y) hline(cx - x, cx + x, cy + y);
            } /* if */
            y--; y2 -= dy2; dy2 -= 2;
        } /* if */
        x++;
        x2 += dx2;
        dx2 += 2;
    } /* while */
} /* bh */

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    char *cols = getenv("COLUMNS");
    char *lines = getenv("LINES");
    int cx, cy;
    int opt;
    int flags = 0;

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "fv")) != EOF) {
        switch(opt) {
        case 'f': flags |= FL_FILL; break;
        case 'v': flags |= FL_TRACE; break;
        } /* switch */
    } /* while */

    argc -= optind;
    argv += optind;

    if (cols && lines) {
        cx = atoi(cols);
        cy = atoi(lines);
    } else { /* try to get from tty */
        struct winsize win;
        int res = ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ, &win);
        if (res == 0) {
            cx = win.ws_col;
            cy = win.ws_row;
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr,
                F("TIOCGWINSZ: %s (errno=%d)\n"),
                strerror(errno), errno);
            cx = 80; cy = 24;
        } /* if */
    } /* if */

    /* center coordinates */
    cx /= 4;
    cy /= 2;

    if (!(flags & FL_TRACE))
        fputs("\033[2J", stdout);

    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        bh(atoi(argv[i]), cx, cy, flags);
    } /* for */
    if (!(flags & FL_TRACE)) {
        puts("");
        fflush(stdout);
    } /* if */
} /* main */
```

it draws amazing circles like this:

```
$ bresenham 5 10
                           * * * * * * *
                       * *               * *
                     *                       *
                   *                           *
$ _              *                               *
               *             * * * * *             *
               *           *           *           *
             *           *               *           *
             *         *                   *         *
             *         *                   *         *
             *         *                   *         *
             *         *                   *         *
             *         *                   *         *
             *           *               *           *
               *           *           *           *
               *             * * * * *             *
                 *                               *
                   *                           *
                     *                       *
                       * *               * *
                           * * * * * * *
```